# TextChanged event in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have two basic textboxes, let's say A and B. I would like input to one textbox to clear any input to the other. For example, type 123 in A. Now type 456 in B. B should contain 456 and A should be empty. However, I receive 56 in B and A is empty. It seems that the first input to B is used to trigger the TextChanged and only the remaining inputs are stored. How can I also pass the first input to the textbox?

Here is my VB.NET code:

```
Public Sub A_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles A.TextChanged
    B.Text = ""
End Sub

Public Sub B_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles B.TextChanged
    A.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TextChanged` event occurs whenever the text is changed, by the user or programmatically.

In your case your `A_TextChanged` eventhandler is changing B's text, so that `B_TextChanged` is called …

Adding some `Debug.WriteLine` statements might help you to understand what's happening: it's difficult to step through with the debugger while you're typing into the TextBox.

To solve it, use a Boolean flag so that you don't modify the other text box when called from one of your event handlers.  E.g. (off the cuff and untested):

```
Private UpdatingTextBox As Boolean

Public Sub A_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs)     Handles A.TextChanged
    If Not UpdatingTextBox Then
        UpdatingTextBox = True
        B.Text = ""
        UpdatingTextBox = False
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub B_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles B.TextChanged
    If Not UpdatingTextBox Then
        UpdatingTextBox = True
        A.Text = ""
        UpdatingTextBox = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't look far enough down the chain of events. That is embarrassing, but another example of the logic behind the machine.

Thanks Joe

Comment: I like how we posted almost the exact same answer, even explanation-wise! Though you were 9 minutes faster than me. +1 :)