# How to check instantly the changes made by user in TextBoxs?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, structure

The procedure allows the modification of text zones by means of an Modify button on the main form. Using a structure, I read and store lines from a text file, and populated according to line number, 3 text boxes. On the other hand, in order to leave it to the user to modify something in these zones if necessary, I would need to know which text zones have been modified! Claude.
Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click

        ' Modifier

        Dim bibliotheque As New article

        With bibliotheque
            .Title = TextBox1.Text
            .Name = TextBox2.Text
            .Charge = TextBox3.Text
        End With

        Dim fileName As String = "c:\essai.librairie"
        Dim someString As String = Trim(TextBox2.Text)
        Dim lignes As String() = File.ReadAllLines(fileName, Encoding.UTF8)
        Dim found As Integer = -1

        For i As Integer = 0 To lignes.Length - 1
            If lignes(i).Contains(someString) Then
                found = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines("c:\essai.librairie", Encoding.UTF8)
        lines(found) = bibliotheque.Title.PadRight(17, " "c).ToString & bibliotheque.Name.PadRight(90, " "c).ToString & bibliotheque.Charge.PadRight(120, " "c).ToString

        MessageBox.Show("Enregistrer les données modifiées ?",
         "Prénommer", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
             MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2)
            If Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                File.WriteAllLines("c:\essai.librairie", lines, Encoding.UTF8)
                Using fStream As New FileStream("c:\essai.librairie", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
                    fStream.SetLength(fStream.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length)
                End Using
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  You can just use the `TextChanged` handler for the textboxes.  Ex. `private sub myhandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtbox1.TextChanged, txtbox2.TextChanged, txtbox3.TextChanged`

Comment: Public Property lst As New List(Of String) _
        From {TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text} Related to the subject, I cannot write the code above?

Comment: You can find examples right here on stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447641/textchanged-event-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the events `txtbox1.changed` or `txtbox1.leave` to take action or flag that textbox as being changed. The `.changed` event fires every time a character is changed. `.leave` only fires when focus leaves the text box.